# How to calculate mean of an iris dataset in r as per the user input , for eg if we enter "setosa" then its mean of sepal length will be printed

Tags: r

How to calculate mean of an iris data set in r as per the user input, e.g. if we enter "setosa" then the mean of sepal length will be printed. I tried using a function but I'm not able to proceed further:

```
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean)
```

but not able to understand how does it work with respect to user input

Comment: What you have tried so far? Kindly provide the sample data.

Comment: tapply(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Species,mean), but not able to understand how does it work with respect to user input

Comment: Looks like you need a function that take as input a `Species` value and returns the mean of `Sepal.Length`

Comment: Working, Thank you Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
n <- readline(prompt="Enter input: ") # Accept input from user i.e. setosa
# Select the rows where Species is setosa and also select the Sepal.Length column (i.e. 
# column 1) and then calcualte mean
mean(iris[iris$Species==n,1])
```

**Output:**

```
  [1] 5.006
```

Comment: Working, Thank you

Comment: This is another option `mean(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species==n])`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
  calc_mean <- function(data = iris,  species = "setosa", col = "Sepal.Length"){
  col       <- which(col %in% colnames(data))
  return(mean(subset(data, Species == species)[, col]))
}
```

And then just call the function with the parameters needed.

```
calc_mean(iris, species = "setosa", col = "Sepal.Length")

[1] 5.006
```